# How to convert colors into strings with the same size?

Tags: python

I'm converting color values to string values, however when I get 0, the string is too short and I have to manually add "00" after it.

Whats the most elegant way to solve this issue in Python ?

```
print "#" + str(self.R) + str(self.G) + str(self.B)
```

if self.R is 0 then I get a too short string.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Can you give some example values of R G and B and what output you want for those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use formatting strings:

`"#%02X%02X%02X" % (self.r, self.g, self.b)`

will give you what you probably want. If you actually want your values to be in decimal like in your example, use `"%03d"` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Python 2.6 or newer you can use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "#{0:02}{1:02}{2:02}".format(self.R, self.G, self.B)
```

If you want hexadecimal (probably you do) then add an X:

```
print "#{0:02X}{1:02X}{2:02X}".format(self.R, self.G, self.B)
```

Comment: I get the following error:     print "#{0:02}{1:02}{2:02}".format(self.R, self.G, self.B)
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier

Answer (score 3):

[Format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) can also resolve qualified attributes:

```
print('#{s.R:02x}{s.G:02x}{s.B:02x}'.format(s=self))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print "#" + str(self.R).rjust(2,"0") + str(self.G).rjust(2,"0") +
    str(self.B).rjust(2,"0")
```

will work fine. It will turn `0` into `00` and `1` into `01` etc.